# BinaryFormattere throwing a FileNotFoundException on a file that exists, why?

Tags: c#, serialization, binaryformatter

I've serialized a file with some atributes with this code:

```
    public void saveLevelInfo(LevelData levelInfo) {
        stream = File.Open("Game.data", FileMode.Create);
        BinaryFormatter bFmt = new BinaryFormatter();
        bFmt.Serialize(stream, levelInfo);
        stream.Close();
    }
```

Then when i try to use this:

```
    public void loadLevelInfo() {
        stream = File.Open("Game.data", FileMode.Open);
        BinaryFormatter bFmt = new BinaryFormatter();
        LevelData level = (LevelData)bFmt.Deserialize(stream);
        stream.Close();
    }
```

I get this exception:
ileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly '922ab9ba88eba49469a1eeab68bc0baa' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

And the file exists, if i erase the file i get this exception:
FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "C:\Users\Gilson\Documents\AntHill\anthill\Game.data"

Any ideas on how to solve that? Im new to C#, so i dont know what to do.

Answer (score 3):

> Could not load file or assembly '922ab9ba88eba49469a1eeab68bc0baa'

It is complaining about an assembly, not the Game.data file.  The assembly name is rather strange to put it mildly.  But in order for BinaryFormatter to be able to de-serialize the object that was stored in Game.data it must be able to load the assembly that contains the LevelData type.  Use the [Fuslogvw.exe tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) to troubleshoot assembly resolution problems, it shows you exactly what assembly the CLR is looking for and where it looked.